# Can't use Caliburn Micro with DevExpress WPF controls

Tags: caliburn.micro, devexpress-wpf

For Common WPF controls I have no problems with using caliburn micro framework, but I can't use it for DevExpress controls. I installed the Caliburn.Micro.DevExpress from NuGet Packages, overrided the configure method in my bootstrapper class and have written DXConventions.Install() in it

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    DXConventions.Install();
}
```

but, the error occurs :

*System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v14.2.Core, Version=14.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'*

How can I solve this problem? Will I be able to use Caliburn.Micro after it?

Answer (score 1):

The code behind the Nuget seems to be compiled with a certain version of the DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.vXX.X which may be different to the one you would have in your source code.

A probable (slightly painful) work around is to build the DLL to support the versions in your source code:

1. The source code for the Nuget can be downloaded from here [Caliburn.Micro.DevExpress](https://github.com/arcticwhite/Caliburn.Micro.DevExpress)
2. Modify the DevExpress DLLs references to the one used by your source code to re-build the Caliburn.Micro.DevExpress project.
3. Refer the DLL (Caliburn.Micro.DevExpress.dll) built from step 2 in your project.
4. Reinstate DXConventions.Install(); in Bootstrapper.
5. Make sure the DLLs covered in Caliburn.Micro.DevExpress project are also present in your source code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this piece of code :

```
static Bootstrapper() 
{
    Caliburn.Micro.DevExpress.DXConventions.Install();
}
```

Let me know how it goes for you ?